Xcode default project config is set to 9.3 how to update this?
Whenever I open a project in Xcode the default project config is set to 9.3.
How do I change the default settings?
Also I occasionally get an error that says something about upgrade to swift 5, however when I check my install from terminal with swift --version I see this:
swift-driver version: 1.90.11.1 Apple Swift version 5.10 (swiftlang-5.10.0.13 clang-1500.3.9.4)


What is your Xcode version? What's wrong with the value 9.3?

my version is 16.0




Project format
Swift Language









For project format, check the Inspectors on the right.
For Swift version, check the Swift Language Version in the project Build Settings.

I know how to set it this way, but I was hoping there would be a way to set it automatically instead of for each project

The project format doesn't automatically increase when you upgrade Xcode. Once you create a project, the project format version is fixed, till you manually change it. If you create a new project with the latest Xcode, it will use the latest default project format version. For Swift Language version, it is defined in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Base/Base_ProjectSettings.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist and Xcode 15 sets it to 5.0.
